# UserType class missing from Cassandra 4.x driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, usertype, cassandra-4.0

I'm using in my java 11 project and migrating the code related to cassandra database from 3.60 to 4.13.0.

```
<cassandra.driver.oss.version>4.13.0</cassandra.driver.oss.version>

            </dependency>-->
            <!-- Cassandra Driver -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
                <version>${cassandra.driver.oss.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>${logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- OPTIONAL DEPENDENCIES -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-driver-query-builder</artifactId>
                <version>${cassandra.driver.oss.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-driver-mapper-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>${cassandra.driver.oss.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

I can see in 3.x there was a class:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.UserType;
```

which seems not to exist any more in 4.x

Is there any substitute for that in 4.x? How can this be handled in 4.x?

I tried searching for this class and/or its substitute in 4.x but with no luck so far.
Just pointing me to this should be enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

As part of [CEP-8](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CASSANDRA/CEP-8%3A+Datastax+Drivers+Donation), **DataStax** has *donated* the **DataStax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra®** to the Apache Software Foundation on Nov 7, 2023. Other language driver donations will be followed shortly.

- The project now lives here at https://github.com/apache/cassandra-java-driver
- The JIRA for issues now lives here at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA under the component ‘Client/java-driver’.
- The mailing list and main communications for java-driver will transition over to [the `user@` and `dev@` lists for Apache Cassandra®](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/community.html).

Your new coordinates for the Java Driver will be,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>${driver.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-query-builder</artifactId>
  <version>${driver.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-mapper-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>${driver.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

with `4.18.0` being the latest version as of this writing, but always recommended to leverage the latest version from [releases section](https://github.com/apache/cassandra-java-driver/tags) of the project.

Having said the current state, `UserDefinedType` class for the `4.x` series lives [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/udts/) & direct link to code is [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra-java-driver/blob/4.x/core/src/main/java/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/type/UserDefinedType.java). You could also take a look at [this test class](https://github.com/apache/cassandra-java-driver/blob/4.x/core/src/test/java/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/type/UserDefinedTypeTest.java) which showcases how to use this.

There is also [this great example repository](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/java-cassandra-driver-from3x-to4x/tree/master/example-4x/src/main/java/com/datastax/samples) that showcases how `3.x` and `4.x` compare and how to implement it.

p/s The above repo still uses the `com.datastax.oss` *groupId*, but you get the concept/point of how to implement.

I hope this helps! Good luck, cheers!